# getting Child functions in Parent class

Tags: c#

I have a class `Room`, a child class `bedroom`, another child class `LivingRoom`.  Now i want to read the number of walls, windows and doors of each of these rooms via common method from the class Room.  Remember room is the parent class.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Both `abstract` and `virtual` methods and properties are suitable for this - here is an example using `virtual` and `abstract` methods - as you can see you **have to** implement/override the `abstract` parts but can stick with the *bases implementation* of the `virtual` parts if you like.

```
abstract class Room
{
    public virtual int WallCount()
    {
        return 4;
    }

    public abstract int WindowsCount();
    public abstract int DoorCount();
}

class Bedroom : Room
{
    public override int WindowsCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override int DoorCount ()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // ... you get the point I hope
}
```

Comment: room should be abstract ??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it has to be if I want to use `abstract` members yes - aside from this it should be `abstract` IMO anyway yes

Comment: if it's abstract we cannot create its instance directly, i was asking from that point of view

Comment: why would you want to create a generic Room? But yes you are right - if you want to create them you have to make it non-abstract which is no problem if you provide `virtual` members instead - the other extreme would be to use interfaces which only have abstract members.

Comment: @Midhun maybe you can accept it then - so this question appears as closed